# Can imported classes use functions and classes from the importing file?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I want to declutter my code a bit and decided to fragment the main file into multiple smaller files.

This was the old setup

```py
coefficient = 2

def foo(x):
    return coefficient*x

class Pair:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Bar:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.x = value
        self.y = foo(value)
        self.point = Pair(self.x, self.y)
```

If I only move `Bar` to `file.py`, import it from there with `from .file import *` and try to use it anywhere in the code, I get a `name is not defined` error for whatever is missing from `file` unless I also move `coefficient`, `foo` and `Pair` there. From this I assume it especially won't work if I move either `foo` or `Pair` to a third file and import from there, which I was also planning to do.

Am I missing something here or is this actually impossible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you should be able to call a function from another file. However, I don't think you can call them if functions from the imported class are based on the file it is imported into as it will be looking for 
'foo' and 'Pair' inside the file for bar.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of. I assume the same goes for classes and global variables in the imported file?